# android shared preferences retrieval

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Hi I'm trying to save a user preference from a list view i'm wanting it to store what the selected and then when the app loads up again checks for the preference chosen method if it = team then do something but at the moment its not loading in preferences any ideas as to what i'm doing wrong. when i log out chosen Method it says null

heres my code

```
preferences.edit().putString("ChosenMethod", "Team").commit();
    preferences.edit().putString("ChosenTeam", ChosenTeam).commit();
    preferences.edit().putString("ChosenTeamId", ChosenTeam).commit();
    preferences.edit().putString("ChosenLeagueId", ChosenTeam).commit();
    preferences.edit().putString("ChosenDivisionID", ChosenTeam).commit();
```

then in the introActivity I've put this this

```
protected void checkPreferences(){


    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
     Log.v("myapp", "prefs = " + preferences);
     String ChosenMethod = preferences.getString("ChosenTeam", chosenMethod);
     Log.v("myapp", "ChosenMethod = " + ChosenMethod);

     if (ChosenMethod != null){

         Intent intent = new Intent(TheEvoStikLeagueActivity.this,Activity.class);

     }




}


            @Override

            public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {

                    super.onCreate(icicle);

                    setContentView(R.layout.main);
                    checkPreferences();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Retrive value from SharedPreference
public static String getStringFromSP(String key) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    SharedPreferences preferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(" SHARED_PREFERENCES_NAME ", android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return preferences.getString(key, null);
}//getPWDFromSP()
```

you can use the above code get value from SharedPreference.
Refer this [LINK](http://asmncl.blogspot.in/2012/04/android-sharedpreference-save-and.html)

Comment: SharedPreferences preferences = _activity.getSharedPreferences(" SHARED_PREFERENCES_NAME ", android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String ChosenMethod = preferences.getString("ChosenMethod", ChosenMethod); heres what i put n it doesn't like the chosenMethod in the brackets